# How to provide detailed feedback user from Authorization Failure in ASP MVC Core Web App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an intranet MVC Core Web App that has Authentication and Authorization and both work.  Rather than dumping the user back to a blank Access Denied page when they attempt to access an action that they are not authorized for, I would like to give them feedback such as the action that they were denied access to and why so that they can speak to their managers intelligently about upping their access level if they have a legitimate need.

I have a custom `AuthorizationHandler` and all of the necessary information is available in `HandleRequirementsAsync`, but there is no way that I have found to actually return the information.  This method only returns `Task.CompletedTask` although it seems that the calling method is aware of changes to `context.Succeed`.

I have not had any luck finding any documentation that roadmaps the authorization process, what methods are called and in what order that allow a request to proceed to the desired action or end up at the access denied page.

It seems that `OnAuthorization` calls `HandleRequirementAsync`, but this is speculation on my part.  There are some examples of overriding `OnAuthorization` but none of those work in the current versions of .Net Core etc...  The closest that I came to was:

```
protected override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext Context)
{

}
```

...but VS reports

```
No Suitable Method Found to Override.
```

On top of that, I found a post from blowdart, the Microsoft Security Guy, that says Don't do it, too great of a chance to break something which may be why there is no documentation on the control flow.

Nearly all of the authorization questions that I have found deal with authorizing someone to do something, not providing meaningful feedback as to why they can't.

I am stuck and could really use some help.

Thank You!!

I am stuck and hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I always thought _"access denied"_ was pretty self explanatory. Anything more than that and you are arguably giving hackers insight as to the inner workings of your system. The user already knows what it is they tried to do when they go to ask their manager for upgraded access

Comment: MickyD - The customer wants detailed feedback.  Since they pay the bills, they get what they ask for.  Hackers and users are polar opposites.  Hackers are paying attention but are not going to get more information than they already have.  Users are barely paying attention and as soon as access denied comes up, they will be on the phone with someone saying I tried to do this thing and it wouldn't let me.  Ask any support person and they will tell you the additional feedback isn't really for the user, it is for who the user calls.

Comment: _"...the additional feedback isn't really for the user, it is for who the user calls.."_ - I think you are mixing _information required to grant access_ with _information required to fix a bug_

Comment: No, I am not.  Within a company, a user tries to access something and gets an Access Denied screen when they believe that they need access.  What do they do?  They call someone, maybe their manager, maybe the IT department.  Regardless of who they call, the more information that they can provide, the quicker the problem is resolved.

Comment: _"Hey Bob, I get an access denied message when I click on the Accounting button"_.   _"No worries Ralph, let me grant you access"_.   QED